# configure the $ key as a "(" key

Tags: linux, keyboard, virtualbox, vnc

We use x11vnc for our vnc servers, Remmina for our VNC viewers, and ssh to tunnel the connections. When workers connect they typically interact with a VBox guest.

When the remote machine is running a VBox guest, parenthesis are not passed through to the VM from the vnc server. Essentially all other keystrokes but parenthesis work. (This is an ancient, apparently unsolved, problem - based on searching the terms: *vnc vbox parenthesis not working*)

I need a work-around that keeps our our current x11vnc/remmina/vbox remote access model and does not use the built-in VBox VNC capability. In an attempt to allow parenthesis to be typed and passed to the VM, I would like try mapping a different key to send the "(" key code to the VM... for example pressing "$" key outputs a parenthesis.

How would I do this?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. Does anyone has found out any way to solve it?